# My DocumentTermMatrix becomes List of 6 when removing sparse terms

Tags: r

```
KeywordsSparse<-removeSparseTerms(Keywords, 0.80)
```

It went from being a Large DocumentTermMatrix(6 elements) to being a List of 6, and now seems to be just a list of numbers from 1-2600 (I had 2600 rows in the dataset).

I tried using 0.70, 0.95.. etc. Same result.

Why did this happen?

Comment: Can you give a fully reproducible example ? Just copy paste all your code. Otherwise, no idea. Keep on !

Comment: Inspect your document term matrix. It might be big, but it also might be completely empty (or only containing 0 values)